# CSS background elements on both sides of the screen

Tags: html, css, background

I want to achieve this: two decoration elements (sort of waves) on both sides of the screen. Here's what I've got so far. If more elegant solution is possible (like styling with CSS only body element), then please advise.
Below solution would be fine, if both < img > elements would not be visible.
You can check this in action.

Here's the working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/53Lgo94v/).

Can you help?

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" >
    <style type="text/css">
        .background_left {
            background-image:url("http://www.destadesign.com/destacms/images/background_border_left.png");
            background-repeat:repeat-y;
            background-position:left;
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
        }

        .background_right {
            background-image:url("http://www.destadesign.com/destacms/images/background_border_right.png");
            background-repeat:repeat-y;
            background-position:right;
            position:absolute;
            right:0;
        }
        .background_left, .background_right {
            height:100%;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="background_left">
        <img src="http://www.destadesign.com/destacms/images/background_border_left.png"> 
    </div> 
    <div class="background_right">
        <img src="http://www.destadesign.com/destacms/images/background_border_right.png">
    </div> 

    <div class="content" style="height:500px;"> <!-- content -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```css
    body {
     background:url("http://www.destadesign.com/destacms/images/background_border_left.png") left repeat-y,url("http://www.destadesign.com/destacms/images/background_border_right.png") right repeat-y;
}
```

This CSS adds two background images to `body`, positions them right or left respectively, and sets the repeat-y, so it doesn't fill the screen.

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/53Lgo94v/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This bare example streches for all window height, which is what I want, but I'm having issues on my more complex page. Perhaps you can give me also a hint, why on my page it stretches only as long as the content and not 100% of height of the window?
http://www.destadesign.com/destacms/page.php?id=8 (you can see at the bottom of the page)

Comment: @JanDesta body only fills as much space as needed, you have to set the html and body's height to 100% if you want it to work: `body, html{width:100%;height:100%;}`